# Set Radius to find a partner turtle

Tags: netlogo

I'm very new at Netlogo and programming in general.
I want to create a netlogo model, with female and male turtles. Both populations move through the world via random walk. The female population should find a partner and has the property 'radius'. Her own radius should expand if she has not found a partner until the moment she finds one. How can I program a radius around the female turtles, that expand after each time step if she has not found a partner?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Sonja23802 - If JenB's answer got you past this particular problem, please mark the answer as "accepted" when you can:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a turtle attribute that stores the value for each turtle. The way to do that is with a `turtles-own` statement. Then you simply change the value as required. The primitive `in-radius` looks at everything within the specified distance, and then you can set a condition by whether there are `any?` suitable mates. Your code would look something like (this is a complete model):

```
turtles-own
[ search-radius
  mate
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color blue
    set search-radius 1
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  check-for-mate
  tick
end

to check-for-mate
  ask turtles with [color = blue]
  [ let candidates other turtles in-radius search-radius
    ifelse any? candidates
    [ set mate one-of candidates
      set color red
    ]
    [ set search-radius search-radius + 0.5 + random-float 1
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot for that awesome help! In that way I understand  the way of coding. I hope I'm not rude to ask you one more thing. I'm a little lost. There's a way to produce turtles from turtles in a hatch command. The idea was hatching randomly  1,2 or 3 turtles / female-turtle after checking for a mate in the radius, and the new turtles have a random gender. Can you give me a hint how to set random gender? Tried it after hatch 1 [ set gender one-of ["male" "female"] ]
but that doesn't work.

Comment: that should have worked. Please do a new question with the full details of what you tried and what happened (error message? what behaviour did you get instead?)